# nodejs bunyan order of elements

Tags: node.js, bunyan

I'm using bunyan, and this is an example of what i'm writting in my log.

Is there a way to change the order of the fields printed? from this:

{"name":"appName","hostname":"ip","pid":5817,"level":30,"**msg**":"message","**time**":"2015-10-15T19:04:01.596Z","v":0}

To this:

{"**time**":"2015-10-15T19:04:01.596Z","**msg**":"message","name":"appName","hostname":"ip","pid":5817,"level":30,"v":0}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the bunyan cli to get a more human readable log.

One option is to pipe just bunyan when you start your app (assuming you are running this from your root directory)

```
$ node app.js | ./node_modules/.bin/bunyan
```

A really short version is to pipe

```
$ node app.js | ./node_modules/.bin/bunyan -o short
```

Search around, there is a lot of power in the bunyan CLI.

https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan#cli-usage